# Clojure - sort function

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a recursive sort function that sorts a list from low to high (duh). I am currently getting output, just not the correct output. Here is my code:

```
(defn sort/predicate [pred loi]
   (if (empty? loi)
     ()
     (if (= (count loi) 1)
       (cons (first loi) (sort pred (rest loi)))
       (if (pred (first loi) (first (rest loi)))
         (cons (first loi) (sort pred (rest loi)))
         (if (pred (first (rest loi)) (first loi))
           (cons (first (rest loi)) (sort pred (cons (first loi) (rest (rest loi)))))
           (cons (first loi) (sort pred (rest loi))))))))
```

Basically, I compare the first two elements in the list and, if the first element is smaller I cons it with the result of comparing the next two elements of the list. If the second element of the list is smaller, I cons the second element with the result of sorting the first two elements of the cons of the first element and everything after the second element (sorry if that's hard to follow). Then, when there is only one element left in the list, I throw it on the end and return it. However, there is a bug along the way somewhere because I should get the following:

```
>(sort/predicate < '(8 2 5 2 3))
(2 2 3 5 8)
```

but instead, I get:

```
>(sort/predicate < '(8 2 5 2 3))
(2 5 2 3 8)
```

I'm pretty new to clojure, so any help is greatly appreciated. Also, I would like to keep my code roughly the same (I don't want to use a sorting function that already exists). Thanks

Comment: I just realized that I'm only ever comparing the first two elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a very efficient way to sort, but I tried to stay true to your intention:

```
(defn my-sort [cmp-fn [x & xs]]
  (cond
    (nil? x) '()
    (empty? xs) (list x)
    :else (let [[y & ys :as s] (my-sort cmp-fn xs)]
            (if (cmp-fn x y)
              (cons x s)
              (cons y (my-sort cmp-fn (cons x ys)))))))
```

Comment: You're right, it wasn't very efficient. I started from scratch and was able to make a merge-sort function that works great.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips Don't leave redundant questions hanging. If you have a good answer of your own, submit it and accept it. Even if your insertion was fixed here, it is as much trouble as doing a merge, which is - as you have found - the basis of a faster simpler algorithm. You can annotate the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

;; merge sort implementation - recursive sort without stack consuming

```clj
(defn merge-sort
  ([v comp-fn]
   (if (< (count v) 2) v
     (let [[left right] (split-at (quot (count v) 2) v)]
       (loop [result       []
              sorted-left  (merge-sort left comp-fn)
              sorted-right (merge-sort right comp-fn)]
         (cond
           (empty? sorted-left) (into result sorted-right)
           (empty? sorted-right) (into result sorted-left)
           :else (if (comp-fn 0 (compare (first sorted-left) (first sorted-right)))
                   (recur (conj result (first sorted-left)) (rest sorted-left) sorted-right)
                   (recur (conj  result (first sorted-right))  sorted-left (rest sorted-right))))))))
  ([v] (merge-sort v >)))
```

Answer (score -2):

`clojure.core/sort` implement by Java more general.

```
user=> (sort '(8 2 5 2 3))
(2 2 3 5 8)
user=> (sort > '(8 2 5 2 3))
(8 5 3 2 2)
user=> (source sort)
(defn sort
  "Returns a sorted sequence of the items in coll. If no comparator is
  supplied, uses compare.  comparator must implement
  java.util.Comparator.  If coll is a Java array, it will be modified.
  To avoid this, sort a copy of the array."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([coll]
   (sort compare coll))
  ([^java.util.Comparator comp coll]
   (if (seq coll)
     (let [a (to-array coll)]
       (. java.util.Arrays (sort a comp))
       (seq a))
     ())))
nil
user=>
```